# Class name is not defined

Tags: python, class

```
class MyClass:
    sample=0
    w=0
    b=0
    g=0
    o=0
    color_list=['black','white','gray']

    def __init__(self):
        print("Enter Your Name")
        MyClass.name=input()
        print("What's the color of ur car?")
        MyClass.color=input()
        MyClass.sample=MyClass.sample+1

    def check_color(self):
        if MyClass.color in MyClass.color_list:

            if MyClass.color==MyClass.color_list[0]:
                MyClass.b=MyClass.b+1
            elif MyClass.color==MyClass.color_list[1]:
                MyClass.w=MyClass.w+1
            else:
                MyClass.g=MyClass.g+1
        else:
            MyClass.o=MyClass.o+1

    def display_result(self):
        print("Hello :",MyClass.name)
        print("Total number of black cars",MyClass.b)
        print("Total number of white cars",MyClass.w)
        print("Total number of gray cars",MyClass.g)
        print("Other cars",MyClass.o)
        print("Sample Size",MyClass.sample)

    var=0
    mylist=[]
    while var<4:
        mylist.append(MyClass())
        mylist[var].check_color()
        mylist[var].display_result()
        var=var+1
```

Error at Python IDLE:

```
==== RESTART: C:/Python34/Practice Programs/TBT Tutorials/Day 4/class.py ====
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Practice Programs/TBT Tutorials/Day 4/class.py", line 1, in <module>
    class MyClass:
  File "C:/Python34/Practice Programs/TBT Tutorials/Day 4/class.py", line 41, in MyClass
    mylist.append(MyClass())
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I fixed your indentation since it looks like the main body of code is in the class definition, could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12729507) your question if I didn't get it right.

Comment: Use `self` to refer to the instance, of which there can be more than one.  `MyClass` refers to the class itself, and is not available until after the class has been defined.  You also have a lot of class-scoped code, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

use `self` instead of MyClass inside your class

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing your class in your classbody:

```
class Myclass:

    ...
    mylist = []
    mylist.append(Myclass)
```

but the term `Myclass` is not defined while executing your class body.

It seems like you mixed up the indentation and it *should be*

```
class Myclass:
    ...
mylist = []
mylist.append(Myclass)
```

which would work.

Besides that you should read about the difference between a class and an object of a class because the code does probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the indenting of the last section of code — the way it is, it's being made a part of `Myclass`, which is in the process of being defined and doesn't exist yet!

To fix that issue just unindent it by one level:

```
class MyClass:
    sample=0
    w=0
    b=0

    ...

        else:
            MyClass.o=MyClass.o+1

    def display_result(self):
        print("Hello :",MyClass.name)
        print("Total number of black cars",MyClass.b)
        print("Total number of white cars",MyClass.w)
        print("Total number of gray cars",MyClass.g)
        print("Other cars",MyClass.o)
        print("Sample Size",MyClass.sample)

# unindent these lines
var=0
mylist=[]
while var<4:
    mylist.append(MyClass())
    mylist[var].check_color()
    mylist[var].display_result()
    var=var+1
```